# Javascript not working in browser? (Firefox, Chrome and Safari)

Tags: javascript

http://pastebin.com/K2miHiAj

That's where the code is located ^

I use both Coda 2 and BBEdit to run the code on and test it, and it works perfectly fine on them! However, whenever I try a browser, the code never runs properly. For this assignment the code has to work on Firefox.

http://oi47.tinypic.com/2lk9yx4.jpg

Comment: The code needs to be located here. Please edit the code (with formatting) into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the function `myFunction` AFTER trying to attach it to the `onclick`, therefore the thing in `onclick="myFunction()"` is *undefined*.
Solution: seperate your JavaScript from your HTML.

```
// attach listener to window.load
window.addEventListener('load',function () {
    // attach listener to your button
    document.getElementById('clickme')
        .addEventListener('click',
                          myFunction,
                          false);
}, false);
```

Look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bgb3F/1/).

---

Edit: complete final code [**here**](http://pastebin.com/MmfbUzfK).

Comment: Hi Paul, it still isn't working :( . I've separated the files like this: html:http://pastebin.com/pT99GT5c, and the javascript: http://pastebin.com/Jsf2uDqT | I don't understand what I'm doing wrong! Thank you.

Comment: By separate the JavaScript, I meant "don't use an `onclick` attrib". When I re-worked it, I noticed you also have a bad invisible character after the last close bracket of your function. I've removed it, validated all your code and re-pastebin'd it for you [**here**](http://pastebin.com/MmfbUzfK).